# whats wrong with this ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, ternary

I have an object `menuNames` which should maintain a list of menu items. If `menuNames` already has the `slug`, increment the value, if it doesnt contain the `slug`, set the value equal to `1`. I'm doing this to track unique names. I want to end up with something like:

```
menuNames: {
    home: 1,
    products: 10,
    contact: 1
}
```

this doesnt work (this would be contained in a loop going through each slug):

```
menuNames[slug] = (menuNames.hasOwnProperty(slug) ? menuNames[slug]++ : 1);
//this sets every value to 1
```

but this does work (this would be contained in a loop going through each slug):

```
if(menuNames.hasOwnProperty(slug)) {
    menuNames[slug]++;
} else {
    menuNames[slug] = 1;
}
```

Comment: You could also just write: `menuNames[slug] = (menuNames[slug] || 0) + 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`menuNames[slug]++` increments the value, but *also* returns the original value.

You are doing `menuNames[slug] =`, so the value is set back to the original value after being incremented.

To fix it, just simply do:

```
menuNames[slug] = (menuNames.hasOwnProperty(slug) ? menuNames[slug]+1 : 1);
```

Or:

```
(menuNames.hasOwnProperty(slug) ? menuNames[slug]++ : menuNames[slug] = 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it could work like this:

```
menuNames[slug] = (menuNames.hasOwnProperty(slug) ? ++menuNames[slug] : 1);
```

Comment: This would work, but it seems inefficient.  `++menuNames[slug]` increments the value and returns the new value, which is then assigned to the variable.  Why do 2 assignments?

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers say the problem is in the post increment.

Another way to write it is:

```
menuNames[slug] += (some_bool ? 1 : 0);
```

`++` is **very** sensitive to bugs. Try to write it as a `+=` statement.

---

if `menuNames[slug]` can be undefined, write it as:

```
menuNames[slug] = 0;
if (some_bool) {
    menuNames[slug] += 1;
}
```

This is (in my opinion) the clearest way to write an initialization/counter loop.

If you like one-liners you'll cringe, but if you like bug free code you'll be happy to see this.

Comment: This wouldn't work if `menuNames[slug]` was `undefined`, as `undefined+0` is `NaN`.

Comment: Added a case if `menuNames[slug]` can be `undefined`